# Which single file embedded DB for a network project?

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access, network-programming

I am looking for an embedded database for a VB 2010 application working over the network. The database file is on a shared network folder on a NAS server (NTFS). For this reason I cannot use any server database like mysql, sql server, etc...

There are nearly 20 PCs accessing the shared folder on the network.
Each pc can open till 3 connections to the database, so we could have till 60 connections to the database. Mostly they just read the database, a writing to the database happens each 5-6 minutes and rarely at the same time, but it can happen.

In the past I had successfully used access+jet for such applications and never had problems, anyway with less network users.

I would still use access+jet (so I do not need to convert the whole database and code), but I would like to use something newer.

I have seen that SQLite is not jet right for network/shared enviroment.
SQL Compact is also not right for shared folder.
VistaDB is too expensive.
Firebird could be an option, but I have no experience: It should be used in a production system and I do not know if I could trust it.

Any suggestion? Or shell I stay by access?

Thanks for replying.

Comment: Why is "newer" a reason to change? For that matter, if you want "newer," try the current version of Jet/ACE, released with A2010, which is available in 64-bit, and has a whole host of great features (such as the equivalent of triggers, for instance). Also, I don't know why with a Jet/ACE back end, you'd want to open multiple connections for each user. Jet/ACE works better with a single connection for each user that is simply re-used (because of the LDB locking file overhead).

Answer (score 0):

Go with firebird. Stable, lightweight, free and very fast as a network and as an embedded database. I am using it everywhere.
However the database cannot reside on a shared network folder. It must reside on a hard drive that is physically connected to the host machine.

VistaDB is good as an embedded database, but has awful performance as a network database because it is not true client-server.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first paragraph rules out any server based solution.